# Android: I can open a file by my app ONLY if I have created (If I copy outside the app, it gets ACCESS DENIED)

Tags: android, file, permissions

[![Folder whith files (beginning)][1]][1]

[image: Folder with files (end)]

In the second image...

- I can open the last file (JSON Web3j credentials).... But I cannot open the before last file (in example)...
- The first (last file) was created by the app... The other was copied there using the Android file manager you see in the pictures.
- So... two files existing, and in the same directory... One is openend by my app, And the other does not!!!

I guess it is a problem of permits,... or something like that.
But I do not know how to open a file not created by my app.

I have permits managed in AndroidManifest.xml and with:

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this
      , Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
          new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
          , Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
          k_id_requestpermissions_external_storage);
    }
```

Can yo help me? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` instead of file permissions.

Comment: I cannot... The problem comes from a method in library Web3j that uses ImputStream. I pass a file as parameter. The file.exists() == true.... But does not open... I need to get permits before opening... And not interactively (the path comes from a configuration file)...

Comment: "I need to get permits before opening" -- that is not an option, sorry. See if the library lets you pass in an `InputStream` directly. Then, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ContentResolver#openInputStream()` will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem and the solution...

UNFORTUNATELY Google Play Console will present a lot of rejections to allow your app to have that permission... (problem->solution->new problem...)

I needed an extra permit:

- AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

- Main Activity... in OnStart (i.e.)

```
intent_activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    , new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
          ResourceBundle in;
          try {
              in = ResourceBundles.getBundle(k_in_ruta);
              if (result.getResultCode() != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                  put_alert("No permit! ");
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              try {
                  put_alert(e);
              } catch (Exception e_ignorar) {}
          }
      }
});
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
    if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager() == false) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction (Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
         Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
         intent.setData(uri);
         intent_activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
}
```